# Passing data as props to one component from another's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components: Album and Songs.
I'm trying to pass the Album component's `id` to the Song component as a `prop`, without having to render the Song component like this:

`<Songs albumId={this.state.id} />`

One possible solution I think could work is, first define a state attribute in Album component for Songs:

```
this.state({id: '', songComponent: <Songs />})
```

Somewhere else in the code grab the albumId and update the state like:

```
this.setState({id: this.state.id, songComponent: <Songs albumId={this.state.id} />
```

And then receive the id in Song component as `this.props.albumId`

I tried this way but `this.props.albumId` keeps coming up as `undefined`. Any solution?

Comment: This is confusing for me, what exactly is the problem with `<Song albumId={this.state.id} />`? (or `this.state.albumId`, it is not clear). Plus `<Songs albumId:{this.state.id} />` should be `<Songs albumId={this.state.id} />`.

Comment: Apologies. Those were typing errors. Fixed now

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by what the problem is? I keep getting `undefined` when i receive the id as props on Songs component.

Comment: Can you show the Album component without typos so that it can be studied more clearly? You still have Song and Songs here. Why do you need the `songComponent` state? What is wrong with just rendering `<Songs albumId={this.state.id} />`?

Comment: Fixed. I don't want to display the Songs component from within Album, because thats being displayed from a different component altogether. But I still need the album ID to be received by Songs component for some tasks.

Comment: Then you have to move the albumId state to the nearest common parent to both components using it. The right way around these problems is a state manager like Redux that will take the state out of the components hierarchy.

Comment: It would be even simpler to aggregate the album ID to the song(s) data when it is fetched. It is even surprising the album ID is not an actual part of the song data in the DB (if the datasource is a DB) or in the API response (if it's an API).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are misunderstanding component composition. 
While trying to decrypt your question, i came to this:

1. There are Album ids and Song ids connected to the Album
2. You not only need to show Songs in Album, but outside of the Album, and store some reference on it.

If i am correct, then i can advise you to use store (whatever you are using, redux, etc..), and collect Album ids from there (**@JulienD** comments for example).

And don't pass whole component to this.setState. State should only contain the minimal amount of data needed to represent your UI's state. It should not contain computed data, other React components, or duplicated data from props.